# defining height of a div to scale

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to define the height of a div without it being fixed to that defined size? For example setting a div to 200px it will be locked to that, and so when it scales it wont change.

I know that you can use % but when I try to do this my image disappears so im forced to using units like px or vw, and im not sure how to create a fluid design without being locked into a specific set size.

Here is my code. I'm wanting .face background image to appear but by using a % it no matter how big I make it, it wont show the image. If I add a px or vw number to its container .topwrap it then creates a large gap to the div container .lowerwrap. So basically I'm trying to find a way to get the image to display itself in a correctly sized div that is able to scale to browser size.

```
/*----------------------------Top ----------------------------*/
.topwrap{
    position:relative;
    top:50px;
    height:auto;
}
.face{  
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    background:url(../images/face2.png) no-repeat;
    background-size:100%;
    top:10%;
    width:50%;
    height:200%;
    display: flex;
    right:16%;
    display: block;
    min-width:160px;
}
.txtwrap{
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:1.3%;
    font-size:1.3vw;
    float:right;                
    right:39%;  
    text-align: center;
}
.sptxt{ 
    color:#171717;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.sptxt2{    
    color:#171717;
    font-weight:400;
}
/*----------------------------Lower----------------------------*/
.lowerwrap{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    top:50px;
    padding-top:10px;
    display: flex;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px #333 inset;    
}
.contentwrap{
    position:relative;  
    width:100%;
    background:url(../images/content.png) no-repeat;
    background-size:100%;
    display: block;
    z-index:1;
}
/*----------------------------Footer----------------------------*/
.footerwrap{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:#09C;
    top:50px;
    text-align:center;  
}
.foottxt{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size:0.5vw;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-weight:200;
    z-index:300;
}
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, a simple img { max-width: 100% } might work?

Comment: where about would you add that line of code?

Comment: A whole new line, you just target the img tag from your html. And take a look at Telinstryata's answer, might be desirable also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we cannot see the HTML that you are applying your styles to, it is difficult to provide a solution. Have you tried using the following on the .face class?

```
min-height: 200px;
```

Comment: think that pretty much solved the issue. I can use px to define the height and it scales accordingly it would seem

Comment: is there a way as to make it so that the browser realizes the height of the browser scale? just to add onto that

Comment: That's beyond my smattering of CSS knowledge. It's probably possible using JavaScript to detect your browser's view window size and then adjust the CSS accordingly, but I'm just chucking out ideas here. I don't know the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow a `<div class="face">` element to resize fluidly based on that percentage width, but maintain a given aspect ratio, try replacing your `.face` rule set with this:

```
.face {
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    background:url(../images/face2.png) no-repeat;
    background-size:100%;
    top:10%;
    width:50%;
    right:16%;
    display: block;
    min-width:160px;
}
.face:before {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    padding-top: 100%;
}
```

The above code assumes face2.png's height and width are the same (a square image, or 1:1 aspect ratio). To make `div.face` fit your actual image, divide your image's height by its width in pixels, multiply that by 100%, and use that for `.face:before`'s `padding-top` value. For example, if face2.png is 180px tall by 120px wide, use `padding-top: 150%;`.

See: http://www.goldenapplewebdesign.com/responsive-aspect-ratios-with-pure-css/